# How to completely scrub an raid disk?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I have started working on raid devices related project. And I would like to be able to test my changes easily.

The problem is whenever I need to create or remove a new raid device, I have to go through troubleshooting lots of silly problems. For example, when I need create a new device, I sometimes get this error message:

```
mdadm: failed to set array info for /dev/md0: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

There are many other example of such silly issues.

Now, I do not have a problem with getting rid of raid device completely. This is a test system after all. So, what would be a good procedure to always follow so that I can reliably delete a raid device and start a new one whenever I need to do so?

I need something a long the lines of : 1. Delete raid devices config files, 2. format devices to delete superblock, and 3. reboot.

I am using CentOS Linux.

Comment: Can you confirm if the raid device includes filesystem or swap? What are the backing devices?

Comment: it does not have a file system. I am using nvme as backing devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to deleted the "raid config files" you simply need to remove your md mount from `/etc/fstab`. Then after unmounting the md device, just use `mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sd#`. This should be all that is required to remove a raid configuration entirely.